# How do I sort the core data values into descending order using swift 3

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, swift3

How do I sort the core data values into descending order using swift 3 and I need code for descending order sort for the below-mentioned code and I want to store first five maximum numbers which is in sorted array into an another array variable

```
import UIKit
import Social
import FBSDKLoginKit
import CoreData

class ViewControllerGame: UIViewController {
    var seconds = 30
    var timer = Timer()
    var cur = 0;
    var d = 0;
    var someValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            scoreLabel.text = "\(someValue)"
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var tapHere: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func highScoreBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        highscoreAlertView(title: "HIGHSCORES", message:"")
    }

    func highscoreAlertView(title:String, message:String){
        let highscorealert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        highscorealert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            highscorealert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(highscorealert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func tapHere(_ sender: UIButton) {
        someValue += 1
        d = self.someValue
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var sliderOutlet: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var startOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func start(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewControllerGame.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startOutlet.isHidden = true
        tapHere.isHidden = false
        scoreLabel.isHidden = false
    }

    func counter()
    {
        if(self.seconds != 0) {
            seconds -= 1
            label.text = String(format: "%02d", self.seconds % 60 )
        }
        if (seconds == 0) {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.label.text = "00"
            createAlert(title: "Your Score is", message: "\(self.someValue)")
            let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let score = ScoreList(context:context)
            score.newScore = Int32(self.someValue)
            appDelegate.saveContext()
            do {
                let result = try context.fetch(ScoreList.fetchRequest())
                let scores = result as! [ScoreList]
                for score in scores {
                    print("Scores: \(score.newScore)")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
            self.seconds = 30
        }
    }

    @IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        shareToFacebook.setInitialText("Timer Game score is \(d)")
        self.present(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.commonthing()
    }

    func createAlert (title:String, message:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "RETRY", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.commonthing()
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "SHARE", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            let shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            shareToFacebook.setInitialText("Timer Game score is \(self.d)")
            self.present(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.commonthing()
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func commonthing() {
        self.seconds = 30
        self.label.text = "30"
        self.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        someValue = 0
        self.seconds = 30
        tapHere.isHidden = true
        scoreLabel.isHidden = true
        startOutlet.isHidden = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you writing to core data every second with a timer, and creating a new entity?

Comment: Reformatted for legibility (mostly just pasted it into a playground, Xcode did most of the work)  The thing that I can't do, that you really need to focus on doing, is to eliminate all the code that's irrelevant to your question and make sure everything needed to answer it is present.  I think, this means you need to eliminate everything other than your `counter()` method since that's where you generate your `NSFetchRequest`, but not sure.